# how can i delete a complete website in EE admin?

Tags: delete

I want to remove a demo website from an installation of expressionengine 2.7.1, I would like to purge all files, channels, entries, templates, everything. Is there a button in the menu what I havent found?

Thanks, Peter

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the Agile Records demo site, you will have to remove it manually. If this is fresh install, the easiest way is to just reinstall EE and unselect the Agile Records demo so it doesn't get installed.

Comment: yes, i want to get rid of tis Agile Records demo site. Then probably we reinstall EE.

Comment: the problem is that layout is not working, the curly brackets showing up on the webpage like this: {layout=layouts/_html-wrapper}

Comment: EE is reinstalled without the demo site, though layouts still not working. any ideas?

Comment: First the Agile Records demo would do nothing to prevent layouts from working. If what you posted is verbatim to your template code, the problem is missing quotes. It should be: {layout="layouts/_html-wrapper"}

Comment: yes, of course in my code I use quotes: {layout="layouts/_html-wrapper"}, sorry to misguide you with my post. But, anyways, it does not work. I suspected demo site made some configuration causing this error, but from fresh install still no good.

Comment: You started with one problem and now have a different problem/question Please create a new question for this new problem and mark this one as  answered.

Comment: oh, i just see that layouts only supported since EE2.8